# Content-Length and Transfer-Encoding headers in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, http, spring-mvc, http-1.1

I'm using Spring MVC and get Transfer-Encoding header in all responses. AFAIK it tells that the response is partial. But at the same time I get all the data, no problems at all. I've found that to disable Transfer-Encoding header generation Content-Length header should be added to response and `ShallowEtagHeaderFilter` filter can help with it. But this filter's purpose is different: to use ETags.

I would like to know is there any problem having Transfer-Encoding header? In which cases I can run into troubles? Is it considered as bad practice, if so why?

Thank you in advance very much!

Comment: I assume you mean in *responses*? And what is the *value* of the header field? If it's "chunked", you may want to read <https://www.greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#chunked.encoding>.

Comment: @JulianReschke yes, it was a mistake, edited the question. Yes, the value is chunked. Ok, I will take a look, thank you!